# Nonseparating curve on a surface and HNN extension

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let S be a closed surface and $\gamma$ be a nonseparating simple closed curve. I was told that $\pi_1(S)$ can be written down as an HNN extension of $\pi_1(S\setminus\gamma)$. Why is that true? What is the precise statement?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What do you know about HNN extensions? Do you know definition? Do you know about group actions on trees?

Comment: Yes I know the definition. It looks like the $\pi_1(S)=<\pi_1(S\setminus\gamma),\gamma\ |\ \gamma s\gamma^{-1}=f(s), s\in\pi_1(S\setminus\gamma)>$ where $f$ is an automorphism of $\pi_1(S\setminus\gamma)$. I don't know which automorphism to put there. Also I know a bit about group action on trees.

Comment: What you wrote in the comment is wrong, not surprising that you cannot make it work. Consider reading for instance https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf pp. 93-94.